# How can I scope use of First to get only the first value in a group?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a report structured as:

```
Org  
   Project  
      Version
```

Each of Org and Project are groups. Version is the detail row and there can be multiple Versions per Project. I need the aggregates at the Project level to be the First value of Version. I tried using "First(Fields!name.value)" and I get first in the dataset scope. I tried "First(Fields!name.value,"table1_project")" where table1_project is the name of the Project group, and I get an error saying the scope parameter is invalid.

Is there a way to scope this so I get the "first" value of Version in the Project row?

SSRS 2012 with VS 2012

This is what the report looks like:
[image]

These are the groups:

[image]

Error message I'm getting:
[image]

table1_project Properties:
[image]

Comment: Can you try `=First(Fields!name.value, "(table1_project)")` and check if it works?

Comment: @Strawberryshrub - nope, that didn't work... Error message added to original post above.

Comment: I dont know ?? Based on your picture with the row groups, your code should work... Can you go to this row group property of `table1_project` and check the name? Or maybe you have this scope in another expression and wrote it wrong there?

Comment: @Strawberryshrub - table1_project properties added above in the original post. I'm glad I'm not the only one confused. I *thought* I had it correct...

Comment: And now it works. This is literally one I tried at least 10 times: =First(Fields!baseline.Value,"table1_project")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this worked:

=First(Fields!baseline.Value,"table1_project")

which is what I tried a dozen times before I posted the original question. I have no idea what happened but it's working now.